# Multiple files upload to Amazon S3

Tags: .net, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

Recently I have downloaded and worked with Amazon S3 .NET SDK. There is a provision to upload a single file at a time. But I want to upload multiple files in single request.

Is there any possibility to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot upload multiple files in a single request, however, you can easily upload multiple files in parallel.

The simplest way would be use the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717.aspx) included in .Net 4.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this article can help you : 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/68775/Uploading-Multiple-Files-To-Amazon-S3-From-ASP-NET

It uses Aurigma Image Uploader